# Janusgraph Docker memory allocation issue

Tags: docker, janusgraph

I am using janusgraph docker image

docker pull janusgraph/janusgraph:1.0.0

and when starting i am providing memory parameter

docker run --cpus 15.5 --rm -d --memory=8g --user 0 -e JAVA_OPTS="-Xms6g -Xmx8g" --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit nofile=100000 --ulimit nproc=65535 -p 0.0.0.0:8182:8182 --name myjanusgraph janusgraph/janusgraph:1.0.0

but still when i check docker stats it shows

CONTAINER ID   NAME               CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %     NET I/O     BLOCK I/O         PIDS

e6d6ed384fe9   myjanusgraph      0.21%     **4.384GiB** / 8GiB     54.80%    656B / 0B   3.28MB / 188kB    48

Not sure **how do i allocate** **8 gb** to docker image.

Thanks,
atul